# Can i send more data using python socket for DDOS attack?

Tags: python, sockets, ddos

Im using [torshammer.py](https://github.com/dotfighter/torshammer/blob/master/torshammer.py) ddos script, its using socket to send random single alphabets and numbers to the target server. My question is can i change the sigle digit number in to large integers? Will this make the attack more powerful?

Changing this code ..

```
p = random.choice(string.letters+string.digits)
        print term.BOL+term.UP+term.CLEAR_EOL+"Posting: %s" % p+term.NORMAL
        self.socks.send(p)
```

Into this ..

```
p = random.randint(1,10000000)
        print term.BOL+term.UP+term.CLEAR_EOL+"Posting: %s" % p+term.NORMAL
        self.socks.send(p)
```

Comment: Depends. Seding random data to random url won't make a good attack. For a good attack, you need a request that will make the server do some work.

Comment: Ok. thank you. Can u suggest me some good Dos scripts if you know any @khajvah

Comment: No. I don't have experience with pen testing (my knowledge is based on logic and a little theory) but you probably can modify the one you used to suite your needs.

Comment: In general DoS attack will open a large number of connections with the server. Usually servers have a limit to the maximum number of connections it can handle at a time. If you exceed this maximum number then the connections will not be established as the server has no free resource to handle this request. Thus now you are (causing) denying the legit users to access the target server and hence the DoS.

Comment: DDoS is in general the same concept but in this case you send requests to the target server from random sources, & in DoS the request are sent to the target server from a same source. `This is very general description & could be obsolete.`

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22809/what-is-a-dos-attack-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-ddos-attack might help!

Comment: Thans for helping,  @ρss

Answer (score 3):

This highly depends on the server. Let's consider a hypothetical scenario where the server has the following function to handle the URL that you are trying to attack.

```
def some_handler(request):
    if len(request.GET.get('param')) > 1:
        return Response(status=401) #random error code
    else:
        #Do some serious computations.
        pass
```

In this scenario, sending data with lenght > 1 will not trouble the server at all, so sending one character will make a better attack.

Comment: So , you are saying that sending a single digit will be more effective than large integer right? Thanks

Comment: @Susmith No, the same argument can be made against single digit. I am saying that it depends on what the server does with that data.

Comment: @Susmith So if you are doing POST DDOS attack, you have to first decide which URL to attack and what kind of data to send in order to keep the connection with it as long as possible.

Comment: @Susmith Khajvah is right. you have to first determine what the target server is actually doing with the requests and other details. This is called as `reconnaissance` phase in pentesting. If you are not able to find the target server's details then you are performing a kind of `blackbox` pentest. In which you pentest a system, that you have no information about. This usually will take a lot of time and patience!

Comment: Ok . then i have to gather all the info of the target server and analyze how the data is processed. Thank you brothers :)